# Объединить метки [rhel] и [redhat]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [rhel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rhel) и [redhat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redhat) так как они фактически, на данный момент времени, являются синонимами. В качестве основной предлагаю сделать [rhel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rhel), это и есть название дистрибутива от Red Hat

---

*Дополнительная информация о метках:*

- метка [rhel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rhel) - 18 вопросов, есть полное описание метки;
- метка [redhat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redhat) - 23 вопроса, описание отсутствует.

---

*Краткое пояснения по теме по просьбе @Suvitruf*

Red Hat Enterprise Linux (он же RHEL) - это дистрибутив Linux, ориентированный на коммерческий рынок, разрабатывается корпорацией Red Hat которую недавно приобрел IBM.
В начале своего пути у этого дистрибутива действительно было название Red Hat, но спустя годы оно сменилось на RHEL (уже достаточно давно).

Под тем что мы понимаем как обычный RHEL (не энтерпрайз) выпускается иной дистрибутив под всем известным названием CentOS, который фактически является на данный момент тем же RHEL, только с вырезанной подпиской и с отставанием где-то в год от энтерпрайз версии.
К примеру, сейчас версия RHEL 8, а версия CentOS 7 и в конце этого года-начале следующего выйдет CentOS 8
Коротко говоря, RHEL платный дистрибутив и у него есть множество модификаций уже ориентированных под нужды тех или иных компаний.

P.S: может местами ошибаюсь, но на оф. сайте написано так, если что подправьте меня.

Comment: А можете пояснить для тех, кто не в теме, суть этих меток? )

Comment: @Suvitruf в вопросе расписать? У RHEL же в описании есть все

Comment: Я просто не в курсе, чем интерпрайз версия отличается от обычной.

Comment: К примеру на Unix&Linux так: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rhel/synonyms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Объединить и сделать [rhel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rhel) основной

Аргументы "за":

- Подобным образом сделано в [сообществе unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rhel/synonyms).
- Вопросов о компании redhat (в отличие от microsoft) не было и вряд ли будет -- не тот масштаб.

Answer (score 0):

Объединить и сделать [redhat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redhat) основной

Answer (score -1):

Ничего объединять не нужно.

Метка redhat - это название компании, так фактически и используется. (примерно так же у нас существует метка windows).

Приравнивать метку дистрибутива rhel к метке компании redhat  -- не очень хорошая идея.

Стоит сделать нормальное описание меток, разово перебрать текущие кучки и при появлении новых вопросов корректировать если будут использованы неадекватные.

Comment: *Фактически, rhel у нас используется как синоним слова linux или lin или *nix* - это не серьезно, это же отдельный дистрибутив, как условно тот же Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu. И сертификация под него намного сложнее чем под вышеозвученные

Comment: У метки RHEL есть нормальное описание

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/rhel/synonyms

Comment: Оставим как есть, значит оставим синонимы и вопросы по RHEL будут прыгать от метки `redhat` к метке `rhel`. Не понимаю какой смысл их держать в таком виде и не совсем понимаю о чём можно задавать вопрос по метке RedHat, коль это о компании? Насколько вкусное у них там кофе, или как? По этой метке можно задавать вопросы на 95% по RHEL, а значит есть смысл синонимизировать её

Comment: @L.F.C. Неплохие аргументы, вписал в голосовалку.

Comment: @L.F.C. тут нет ни вины метки `RedHat`, ни  вины `rhel`. У меня к примеру RH совсем с rhel не ассоциируется. У RedHat есть сервер WildFly. Тут скорее вина пользователей, тыкающих эту метку куда не надо.

По хорошему эту метку надо просто удалить, точнее внести в блок-листы, но такого механизма тут нет.